Cloud run: restrict traffic from firebase hosting?
I'm building an app with React as front end and hosted on firebase hosting.
I'd like to build an api server for the front, and considering Fastapi + Docker deploy to Cloud Run.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run#direct_requests_to_container
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/integrate/firebase-hosting
I found these 2 tutorials about how to connect firebase hosting to cloud run, but I'd like the Cloud Run to only accept accesses from firebase hosting app.
Is there any way to achieve this?
===== update ============================================
I read from https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing that

Requests are only billed when they reach the container after successfully being authenticated, requests denied by IAM policy are not billed.

And under that link in the quote, there's a document about how to Authenticating end users  https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users
and a detailed tutorial https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/identity-platform

Using Firebase Authentication is similar to using Identity Platform.

I'm a little confused about the authenticating.
Does it mean I can:

auth the user with firebase authentication
get an idToken and put it in header
at cloud run api server, check the token

if no token or invalid token, return 401 or 403, request is NOT billed
if valid token, process, request is billed



Is that right?

Cloud Run does not have a firewall in the traditional sense. Cloud Run uses authorization or lack thereof to control access. See this document link: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users#cicp-firebase-auth

@JohnHanley thanks. Firebase function can restrict access to be only from the hosting, so I wondered if cloud run has same ability. If it not possible with cloud run, how could I protect the service from attack, to prevent unexpected billings?

AFAIK - Cloud Run uses the same mechanism as Functions. Did you read the document I referenced?

@JohnHanley yes, and that's why I updated the question

I have the same issue and I used firebase APP CHECK.
App Check helps protect your API resources from abuse by preventing unauthorized clients from accessing your backend resources. It works with both Google services (including Firebase and Google Cloud services) and your own APIs to keep your resources safe.
Steps:

Add App Check to your app, using either the reCAPTCHA Enterprise provider or a custom provider https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/custom-resource#before_you_begin
Send App Check tokens with backend requests https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/custom-resource#send_tokens_with_backend_requests
Verify App Check tokens from a custom backend https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend


any affiliation? /help/promotion also, please show how to use it to solve the problem in the question.

Thanks, so app-check is not only for firebase services, I can use it in a cloud run service too? What about the billing, do you understand when a request is not billed? when the token does not exist or failed?

Yes it can be used in cloud run, you must add token verification to your backend before each action, so it will exit quickly if there is an invalid token. so there will be no expenses
